# Passing a two-dimensional array in C function

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to return a two-dimensional array from a function, but something goes wrong. `arr2` on the main function is getting an error,

> CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated

#### Code

```
int** file2array(char* filename) {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    int arr[9][9];

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            c = fgetc(fp);

            if (c == '.') {
                arr[i/9][i%9] = 0;
                i++;
            }

            if (c>= '1' && c<='9') {
                arr[i/9][i%9] = c - 48;
                i++;
            }
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }

    return arr;
}

int main(){
    int** arr2 = file2array("SolverInput.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 2D array `int arr[9][9]` and a pointer to pointer `int **arr` are not interchangeable, use a pointer to an array `int (*arr2)[9]`:

```
void *file2array(char* filename){
    ...
    int arr[9][9];
    ...
    return arr;
}

int (*arr2)[9] = file2array("SolverInput.txt");
```

But note that `arr` is a local variable (his lifetime ends whith the function), use `malloc`:

```
void *file2array(char* filename){
    ...
    int (*arr)[9] = malloc(sizeof *arr * 9);
    ...
    return arr;
}

int (*arr2)[9] = file2array("SolverInput.txt");
...
free(arr2);
```

If you don't know the number of elements before-hand (an arbitrary number instead of 9) you can use a variable-length-array (VLA)

```
void *file2array(char* filename, int dim){
    ...
    int (*arr)[dim] = malloc(sizeof *arr * dim);
    ...
    return arr;
}

int dim = 9;
int (*arr2)[dim] = file2array("SolverInput.txt", dim);
...
free(arr2);
```

Also, `fgetc()` returns an `int` (not a `char`)

Change

```
char c;
```

to

```
int c;
```

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot

second, should i free only arr2 or should i free each and every index?

Comment: Only `arr2`, contents are in the same block, the rules are: if you call `malloc` n times you must call `free` n times too. You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays behave weirdly when then are passed as function parameters. That's how it is in C. Just don't do it.

Instead, you should embed the array in a `struct`.

```
typedef struct {
    int cell[9][9];
} sudoku;
```

You can then pass a `sudoku *` instead of an `int **` to the function. This has the immediate benefit of telling the reader of your code what it does. An `int **` can mean pretty much anything, but a `sudoku *` cannot.

```
int read_sudoku(const char *filename, sudoku *sud) {

    if (some error happens)
        return -1;

    sud->cell[3][8] = 5;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    sudoku sud;

    if (read_sudoku("sudoku001.txt", &sud) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot read sudoku\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ...
}
```

This is the simplest it can get. No `malloc`, no `free`, just some code that does the actual work.